# Student average - No response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

this code suppose to accept 4 subject marks from the user and calculate total and average.
and it should display in the text Box.

When i click on Calculate(button) it should generate an alert dialog box and some calculation, but it's not. 
what is the error in it? what's wrong?
i just cant figure out what's wrong in this code..everything looks Fine to me !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>ass_3 q_6</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function average()
        {
            alert("Hay");
            var s1=document.getElementById("math").value;
            var s2=document.getElementById("phy").value; 
            var s3=document.getElementById("che").value; 
            var s4=document.getElementById("bio").value; 
            var total=document.getElementById("tot"); 
            var ave=document.getElementById("avg");

            tot.value= (s1+s2+s3+s4);
            avg.value=(tot.value)/4;

        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2 class="c1">Student Marks Average</h2>
<form name="myMarks" method="post" action="" id="myMarks">
<table align="middle" border="1">
<tr><td>Subjects</td><td>Marks Out of 100</td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="90px">Maths:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="math" name="maths" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Physics:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="phy" name="physics" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chemistry:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="che" name="chemistry" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Biology:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="bio" name="biology" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="middle"><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="average()" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c2">
<td>Total:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="tot" name="total" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c3">
<td>Average:</td>
<td><input type="text" id="avg" name="average" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I'd highly recommend using something to debug with. I really like the Javascript Console in google chrome. The error that comes up is that your type "average" is not a function.

From that, you can see that maybe you have more than one thing defined as "average". In fact, you've got your input type named "average" as well.

Just change the name of your function or the name of your input type and it works perfectly!

For example, I changed to

```
onclick="average_calc()"
```

and the function to

```
function average_calc()
```

... and it worked fine.

("fine" meaning only that you got values in the text boxes ... you're not adding them yet, you're concatenating them, and you're selecting "tot" directly ... so still a few issues, but this should move you down the road)

Comment: Exactly right. To the OP don't name your input fields and your functions with the same name (average).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these lines right here:

```
        var total=document.getElementById("tot"); 
        var ave=document.getElementById("avg");

        tot.value= (s1+s2+s3+s4);
        avg.value=(tot.value)/4;
```

They are causing your script to stop running, because `tot` and `avg` are not defined. Instead, you have `total` and `ave`. Make them match and it should run.

Edit: As AndyMac pointed out, another problem lies in the function having the same name as one of your inputs. Also, your variables are going to have string values of the numbers in the inputs, so your output will not be what you expect. To solve this, use `parseInt` to get integer types.

```
function calc_average()
{
    alert("Hay");
    var s1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("math").value);
    var s2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("phy").value);
    var s3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("che").value);
    var s4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("bio").value);
    var tot = document.getElementById("tot");
    var avg = document.getElementById("avg");

    tot.value = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
    avg.value = tot.value / 4;
}
```

Comment: i changed to    total.value= (s1+s2+s3+s4);
   return ave.value=(tot.value);

Comment: Probably good practice to select the element explicitly like you're doing in the var declaration. This is "working" to set values, but you've got different names (total vs tot) in the selectors ... probably not working on all browsers, though.

Comment: it's working...just changed the function name to average_calc()..Recommended by @AndyMac Thanks....

Comment: Yea, that was a good catch by him. My original answer was just what immediately stood out to me. I didn't even know you couldn't have elements and functions with the same names, so thanks to him for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
the problem in function name and some code please try this function

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function get_average()
{
alert("Hay");
var s1=parseInt(document.getElementById("math").value);
var s2=parseInt(document.getElementById("phy").value); 
var s3=parseInt(document.getElementById("che").value); 
var s4=parseInt(document.getElementById("bio").value); 
var total=document.getElementById("tot"); 
var ave=document.getElementById("avg");

tot.value= s1+s2+s3+s4;
avg.value=(tot.value)/4;

}

</script>
```

Comment: it's working...just changed the function name to average_calc()..Recommended by @AndyMac Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Your function lacks a return statement. If you put a "return avg.value" in the end of it, then you could display it elsewhere after calling the function.